# How can I send the modal dialog parameter sent from html from the typescript page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have one dialog window using Angular. I can open this dialog window by sending a parameter on the html side and sending a transaction. I want to make my page more functional by using the fab button. For this, I need to be able to send the parameters I send to my dialog window on the html side when calling the modal function on the typescript side. Can you help me with this?

**.html file((click)="editPdf(responsiveData)")**

```
.... <!-- The part to be deleted -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle mr-3" (click)="editPdf(responsiveData)"> <i class="fe-edit"></i></button>
...
<div>
<div id="fab-dismiss"
     *ngIf="fabTogglerState==='active'"
     (click)="onToggleFab()">
</div>

<div class="fab-container">
  <button mat-fab class="fab-toggler"
          (click)="onToggleFab()">
    <i class="material-icons" [@fabToggler]="{value: fabTogglerState}">settings</i>
  </button>
  <div *ngFor="let btn of buttons" [@speedDialStagger]="buttons.length">
    <button *ngIf="btn.show"
            mat-mini-fab
            class="fab-primary"
            matTooltip="{{btn.tooltip}}"
            matTooltipPosition="left"
            color="accent"
            (click)="onClickFab(btn)">
      <i class="material-icons">{{btn.icon}}</i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ResponsiveData content**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQsqq.png)

**Typescript**

```
...
FabOptions = {
    buttons: []
}
buttons = [];
fabTogglerState = 'inactive';
  fabButtons(ap: extendedAppeal) {
this.FabOptions = {
  buttons: [
    {
      ...
    {
      id: 9,
      icon: 'create',
      show: ((this.pdfguncelle) && (ap.status === this.appealStatus.Waiting) &&(this.authService.currentUser().agentOf.indexOf(ap.branchOfficeId) > -1)) ? true : false,
      tooltip: "Dilekçe Düzenle"
    },
    ...
  ]
};
}

showItems() {
   this.fabTogglerState = 'active';
   this.buttons = this.FabOptions.buttons;
}
hideItems() {
   this.fabTogglerState = 'inactive';
   this.buttons = [];
}

onToggleFab() {
   this.buttons.length ? this.hideItems() : this.showItems();
}

onClickFab(btn) {
    .../* Part to add */
    //else if (btn.id === 9) this.editPdf() /* I have to change this line to open the dialog window */
 }

 editPdf(content: any) {
    ...
    this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the modal reference on the typescript side by using a `ViewChild`. In the typescript, add:

```js
@ViewChild('responsiveData') responsiveData: TemplateRef<any>;
```

You can then open it from `editPdf` without having to pass the reference from the template:

```js
editPdf() {
   ...
   this.modalService.open(this.responsiveData, { centered: true });
}
```